# Bytes streams processing in Java over a socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am not expert in Java socket programming but I'm currently trying to develop a server/client application in Java.

The client should send messages to the server with different parameters(header) and data(body). In the received message some of parameters must be removed and remaining parameters and data should be sent to another server. The Client's sending data packet size is predefined as:

```
MAX_SOCKET_BYTE_LEN=24576
```

Can anyone give me ideas how to implement messages byte stream processing over socket connections, for my case?

Comment: What you are trying to do is fairly straight forward and many java web servers use something similar. What have you tried?

Comment: @shazin -- you are correct, here what I'm doing is manipulating inputstream bytes in high level.

Comment: For more complex protocols in the future you might want to consider xml messages: http://jaxb.java.net/

Comment: @pradeekrathnayaka if you are looking for a framework netty is the best as mikera said. Its so easy to learn, good support and interserver communication is so simple in netty(We can use the same handler for server and client messages). also try if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a very good reason otherwise, I'd suggest learning and building upon one of the very good existing communication frameworks, e.g. Netty:

- http://netty.io/

This will handle a lot of the complexity that you would otherwise need to deal with yourself in socket communications.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to use this framework(http://netty.io/) it has many capabilities

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples, try buffers instead of bytes, lets check this example [Nio Examples](http://javabeginershub.blogspot.in/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using mikera suggested framework